# Adding tags to Images a cross between facebook & map pointers

Tags: iphone, image, ios, text, tags

I intend to make an app that adds a layer of text or pointers to images.
Kinda like adding another layer text/pointer over an image displayed in iphone.

ALSO, upon exporting, i want that image with the added text over it to be clubbed with the new "exported" image.

Im puzzeled as to how to start this..?

any ideas or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way is to add all the load the uiimageview, and the other views on a single parent view and

```
@implementation UIView (Imaging)

-(UIImage *) getSnapshotImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height));
    CGColorSpaceRef color = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGColorSpaceRelease(color);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}

@end
```

once you have the UIImage, convert it to JPEG or PNG using

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

which you can then proceed to store it in a file

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. I needed kinda more understanding of the whole approach. Like I use UIImageView to extract the image from either cameraroll or new image from cam, Using touch, i draw perhaps a line or text via uilabel. Programmatically how to i link the imageview with either uilabel or line.?

Comment: what this does is, it tries to draw the entire view hierarchy(the view and its subviews) into the newly created image context. So what you see on the screen is what you will get in the image context as well.